# Coefficient of Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series

I'm currently studying Fourier Series and this is my lecture note[Fourier Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQoif.png)

But when im doing revision and i found this
[Fourier Series 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMfiN.png)

Can i know what is the difference between these two?Why are the coefficient is different?

Comment: T=2L is just different representations of the period.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, if you see the first case the integral is calculated over the interval $[t_o,t_o+T]$ and hence the length of the interval is $T$. On the second case the integral is calculated over the interval $[-L,L]$ and then the length is now $2L$. Dividing by $T$ or by $2L$ is analogous.

Comment: I see... Thanks!